# Nodejs - Pass variables between functions (Post with Ndeedle)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post

Im using Needle to do a POST http , then i need to receive back the response ( its some key ) and use it in another POST request.

```
const needle = require('needle');
const x = needle.post('https://example.com/connect/token' ,
   {
       grant_type: 'password',
       username: 'some_user_name',
       password: 'some_password' , 
       client_id : 'swaggerui',
       client_secret : 'no_password',
   }
   , (err, res) => 
   {
       if (err) 
       {
           console.error(err);
       };
       console.log((res.body).access_token);
   }

);
```

now I need to get the `((res.body).access_token)` into some var and use it again in another POST , how can I achieve that?

Comment: Well, you're getting it and using it in another function (`console.log`) already. So what's the problem with replacing `console.log` with the function you want to get it to?

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with JavaScript I'm just learning it now and I'm trying to do this , can you please show me what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There are three approaches to it.

> and use it in another POST request.

1. You put the *second POST* in the callback of the first request:

```js
const needle = require('needle');
needle.post('https://example.com/connect/token' ,
   {
       grant_type: 'password',
       username: 'some_user_name',
       password: 'some_password' , 
       client_id : 'swaggerui',
       client_secret : 'no_password',
   }
   , (err, res) => 
   {
       if (err) 
       {
           console.error(err);
       };
       else {
           needle.post('<url>', {
               key: res.body.access_token
           });
       }
   }

);
```

2. You can define a callback function that makes the *second POST* with the `res.body.access_token` passed to it as an argument.

```js
const callback = (access_token) => {
    // ...
    doSomethingWithAccessToken(access_token);
    // ...
}

needle.post('<url>', {
    // ...
}, (err, res) => {
    // ...
    callback(res.body.access_token);
})
```

3. You define a global variable and in the callback function you set the value of it to be `res.body.access_token`

```js
// ...
var access_token = "";
needle.post('<url>', {
    // ...
}, (err, res) => {
    // ...
    access_token = res.body.access_token
});
```